# phpMyAdmin and mysql not showing the same users or databases

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, mamp

You will have to excuse me as I am new to the world of PHP and Mysql.

I have setup PHP, Mysql and Apache (using MAMP to connect on a localhost) which I managed by using a tutorial and everything seems fine... I am logging into mysql as the root user with full privileges granted and I am able to create databases in mysql and view them by using SHOW DATABASES; so far so good !

...However...

When I access phpMyAdmin and go to the databases section, there are no databases which I have created in mysql, even though phpMyAdmin shows the Database server as User:root@localhost which is the same user I am accessing mysql with.

This situation is also the same when reversed, I can create a database as the root user in phpMyAdmin but the database will not show in mysql when I am logged in as root user and use SHOW DATABASES;

I am figuring this probably just has something very to do with my lack of understanding and I apologise if this is a very basic question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you 100% certain you've logged in to the same database? Look on the left, phpMyAdmin can show multiple databases.

Comment: I have 3 Databases in PHPMyAdmin which are the default information_schema, mysql and performance schema... I also have these when i use SHOW DATABASES in mysql but I have the additional ones I created in mysql... really puzzling me ?

Comment: What user did you log in to mysql with?

Comment: Am I even right in thinking the PhpMyAdmin and mysql should mirror behaviour... so if I create a DB in mysql it will show in phpMyAdmin under databases ?

Comment: logged into mysql with mysql -u root -p... then entered my password

Comment: what's the names of the databases you've created on phpmyadmin and on mysql?

Comment: I created a database called user_info in mysql which is not displayed in phpMyAdmin... also I used the default MySql port through MAMP which is 8889 and phpMyAdmin shows the server as localhost:8889 (didn't know if this was relevant but thought I would mention it).

Comment: Look in your phpmyadmin config file and search for "hide_db". What does it have set there?

Comment: Sorry for being so useless, what is the best way to find this out ?

Comment: open the phpmyadmin config file (search on google to find where that's located), then do a "find" for the word `hide_db` in that file. print here what that line says.

Comment: Okay I think something is really wrong as I opened my php config as per the guide and everything looked the same as the guide and I was able to search for other things (ie: display_errors) but when I searched for hide_db is was not found... I might just pull my hair out and scream ! Is there a quick fix to start EVERYTHING from the beginning again as I have been trying to get my head around this all day... by the way, thank you very much for your help so far !

Comment: it's very difficult to diagnose over the internet, especially without error messages. i'd suggest googling for similar issues first, then starting over from scratch if that doesn't work

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will have a look and post if I find the answer/cause. Thanks again !

Comment: I think I am finally getting somewhere now ! I managed to find the hide_db that you said about, it is in the config.default.php file which I know is NOT to be edited and I believe I now have to include it in a config.inc.php file with the relevant changes. Does this make any sense thus far ? Thank you

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '';

Comment: if it's blank (empty string), then that's not the cause. it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are logging into phpMyAdmin from your browser and that both are pointing to the same host, ie. no not a virtual host, you MySQL might be on virtual and phpMyAdmin on localhost etc.

Answer (score 1):

Better stop MAMP and access the Mysql using command prompt mysql -u -P -p password